# SQL add an url to every row of a column with the file name number incrementing

Tags: sql, pervasive-sql

I imported an excel table to pervasive sql but when I checked the table, every row was imported except for the picture column rows. I saved the excel pictures into a folder and am trying to add an url of the picture to every row where it belongs.

The picture name are as follows: image001.png, image003.png, image005.png and so on. I would like to know how i could use a sql statement to add the url to every row with and increment of 2:

```
"\images\image001.png"
"\images\image003.png"
"\images\image005.png"
"\images\image007.png"
```

And so on.

My table structure is the following:

The table name is "products" and has the following columns:

```
"SCL No." CHAR(50) CASE ,
"Cus No." CHAR(80) CASE ,
"OEM" CHAR(50) CASE ,
"Description" CHAR(110) CASE ,
"Q'ty" CHAR(10) CASE ,
"Unite" CHAR(10) CASE ,
"FOB" CHAR(10) CASE ,
"Amount" CHAR(10) CASE ,
"Remark" CHAR(40) CASE ,
"Picture" CHAR(100) CASE
```

The order of the urls is sequential: in the first row "\images\image001.png", in the second row "\images\image003.png" and so on... Incrementing the image number by 2.

I'm using pervasive sql control center version 9.50.

I don't want to do it manually because there are like 600 rows.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe the table structure

Comment: The table name is "products" and has the following columns: "SCL No.", "SCL No.", "OEM", "Description", "Q'ty", "Unite", "FOB", "Amount", "Remark", and "Picture"

Comment: Please edit your question with the table structure. Also, what describes the ordering of the rows in the table? For example, how do you know which row gets image 001?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Pervasive SQL control center Version 9.50

Comment: You said "the first row" gets image001.  What defines the "first row"?

Comment: "SCL No." Even though some "SCL No." can be duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything much about pervasive sql, but on the basis of what you've described, I would say you just need an update statement which does this (you'll need to translate it to your brand of SQL):

There is also one question about numbering given you're incrementing by two and have 600 rows, but your numbering example only provides for numbers from 1 - 999, so I'm putting them in the format 0001 ->

```
UPDATE Products SET Picture = '\images\image' + Right('000' + LTrim(RTrim(Cast(((RowID() * 2) - 1) as varchar(4)))), 4) + '.png'
```

I think the parentheses are correct, but even if they're not I think you should see what I've tried to convey.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering, i seem to understand the basic notions of the code but is giving me an error on the expression, would have to see what it is about.